# OpenLayers3 Custom Scale Select Options: Calculation needed

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm a newbie using OpenLayers 3 and having the following problem:
I've created a custom control (select box; see image) where I would like to add 3 predefined scale options (see code after image).

[image]

```
let option2 = new Option('1 : 150.000', '2183910.7260319907', false, false);
option2.id = 'opt2';
select.appendChild(option2);

let option3 = new Option('1 : 30.000', '2183910.7260319907', false, false);
option3.id = 'opt3';
select.appendChild(option3);

let option4 = new Option('1 : 15.000', '2183910.7260319907', false, false);
option4.id = 'opt4';
select.appendChild(option4);
```

From other sources I've found that I "simply" need to pass the correct value (above it would be **2183910.7260319907** for the 1:2M scale) to the respective scale option and then I've already implemented the set resolution function in order to update the map.

**Question: How can I now calculate that particular value (I don't even know what it represents...) for the scales of 1:150.000, 1:30.000 and 1:15.000?**

Thank you so much in advance & if something is not clear, I'm happy to clarify and provide more code/screenshots if necessary.

Cheers :)

Comment: You should also show the section of your code where you apply the scale to the map. Do you use `setResolution()` on your map's `ol.View` instance?

Answer (score 1):

In web cartography, we work with resolutions, not scales. Resolution simply means map units per screen pixel.

If you want to apply the concept of paper map scales, you'll need to make assumptions about the resolution of the user's screen, which is usually expressed in dots per inch (dpi). Then you can calculate the scale like this:

```
var inchesPerMeter = 39.3700787;
var dpi = 96;

function getResolutionForScale(scaleDenominator) {
  return scaleDenominator / inchesPerMeter / dpi;
}
```

To use this, simply use the scale denominator as value in your options. So e.g. `2000000` for the "1 : 2.000.000" scale. Then it is easy to apply the scale to the map:

```
map.getView().setResolution(getResolutionForScale(scaleDenominator));
```

Side note if you want to get super accurate: projections like Web Mercator have different resolutions for different latitudes. To accommodate for that, you could use `ol.proj.getPointResolution()` to get the true resolution for a specific location on the map, and adjust the result from `getResolutionForScale()` accordingly:

```
var view = map.getView();
view.setResolution(ol.proj.getPointResolution(
    view.getProjection(),
    getResolutionForScale(scaleDenominator),
    view.getCenter());
```